# If the composition map $f_j = y_j \circ f \in k[V]$, then the map $f: V \rightarrow W$ is a polynomial map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am not able to prove the following result:

Let $V \subset \mathbb{A}^n, W \subset  \mathbb{A}^m$ be algebraic sets.

If the composition map $f_j = y_j \circ f \in k[V]$, where $y_j$ is the coordinate function on $\mathbb{A}^m$ , then the map $f: V \rightarrow W$ is a polynomial map.

My attempt: Let $f_j = F_j \pmod{I(V)}$.

Claim: $f = (F_1, \dots, F_m)$ is the polynomial map.
Proof: Let $G \in I(W)$. If we can show that $G(F_1(p),\dots, F_m(p))=0$ for all $p \in V$, then we are done. How do we show this?

Comment: What is $V$? What is $y_j$???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Edited.